# How to run some vps together with database in another server?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I need to run django site and some scripts together on vps server. But scripts has a large load on the server. Therefore, I assume creating 4 VPS, 1 for the site, the second for the database and the remaining 2 for scripts. And i need to somehow connect them to the database. What technology can be used to achieve this? As I understand it, large companies use several servers to distribute loads, I want to do the same.
I only have experience installing Django with postgresql on Nginx with Gunicorn on one vps

Comment: How do you know that the scripts are causing a heavy load on the server? Have you monitored the CPU and memory usage while running them? How much traffic do you reasonably expect to receive for the Django site? It might be more efficient to just vertically scale your one server (as in, increase CPU and memory resources) than start working with a multi-server setup, which can be a hassle to maintain unless you're ready to dive into IaaC.

Comment: But to answer your question: it's not much different from setting up Django + Gunicorn + Nginx + Postgres in one VPS, which you already know how to do. Just install Nginx + Gunicorn + Django on one server, and Postgres on another, and configure your Django instances to connect over the network instead of to localhost. You just need to make sure you have the networking set up right (and securely). With services like AWS, the Postgres server is usually set up as a managed service, e.g. Amazon RDS. DigitalOcean and other cloud providers also have similar managed database services.

Comment: @DJRamones Thank you very much for your extensive answer. Now i understand that it is easier to increase the power of one server for me than to plunge headlong into horizontal scaling.